# RViz - RobotModel -> base_link -> 'show trail' history

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to display the trail of my robot in RViz. I know that it's possible by publishing a visualization_msgs/Marker something like in this tutorial: [Markers: Points and Lines (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines). However, at first I'd like to know if it's possible to do it easier way using display type RobotModel -> Links -> base_link -> show trail. Yes, it draws a path of my robot but only a small part of it - after a few seconds of driving the beginning is 'erased'. Is it possible to make the history/lifetime (not sure how to exactly call it) of my trail longer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199552/rviz---robotmodel--%3E-base_link--%3E-%27show-trail%27-history/) by [zaslon](https://answers.ros.org/users/20711/zaslon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few options (such as implementing your own marker-based visualization or modifying the rviz plugin source to make the trail longer). However, I also required this functionality in the past, so I implemented the [hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) package. It publishes the path of the robot as a [nav_msgs/Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html), which can be easily visualized using the corresponding rviz plugin.

The easiest way to get the package is to

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam
```

(replace indigo with your ros distro if it's not indigo)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zaslon](https://answers.ros.org/users/20711/zaslon/) on 2014-12-16**:
Thank you very much, it works perfectly!